# Intellij can not recognize java.util.List

Tags: intellij-idea

When I input `List` in Intellij, it doesn't automatically provide a prompt for importing `java.util`. I have to import `java.util.List` manually.

When I write `java.util`, it doesn't prompt to add `List`, but instead `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Please check File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from Import and Completion. If `java.util.List` is there, remove it.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. oh my god,that confuse me a long time.Thanks very very very much.

Comment: Just fixed the same problem again. Wanna vote one more time, hahaha.

Comment: thanks! what am i missing? why is this the default behaviour?

Comment: It's not the default behavior. Most likely List was added there accidentally, e.g. by pressing Alt+Enter + Enter during completion or auto-import popup.

Comment: +1000 , you saved my day, just wondering how come it added to exclude import lists?

Comment: IntelliJ on Macos: IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | (in the search box type: "auto import")

Comment: This made my day @PeterGromov

Answer (score 8):

in my case, suddenly nothing from java.* was recognized.
tried setting different JDK's in File->ProjectStructure, then File->Invalidate Caches/Restart made it work again!

Comment: thx man you helped me a lot

Comment: Nowadays there's also the [Repair IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/repair-ide.html) option. Unfortunately it still does not work for me: [List#of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--) and [Stream#toList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) remain unrecognized despite Java language level being set to 17.

Answer (score 2):

Reopening the project fixes the auto-import for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in code completion in versions 2022 and above.
of course manually import the package sort the issue.
Based on my understanding the issue reproduced the time the UI is busy updating maven indexes especially when memory is low

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).